# Tangent Space of SL(n,R) at arbitrary point, e.g. not at $\mathbb{1}$

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am looking for the tangent space of $SL(n,\mathbb{R}) = \{A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} | \det{A}=1 \}$ (actually $n=3$) at an **arbitrary** $M\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})$. From now on I will omit the $\mathbb{R}$ for convenience.

It is well known and easy to prove that the tangent space at the identity matrix $\mathbb{1}$, $T_1SL(n)$, is the set of all traceless matrices of the same size.

However I am not able to generalize this result. These are my thoughts:

Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to SL(n)$ be a curve with known $\gamma(0) = M$ and unknown $\gamma^\prime(0)=X$. Let's differentiate the $SL$-characteristic equation: $$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\det{\gamma}(t) = D(\det)|_{\gamma(0)}\,\cdot\,\gamma^\prime(0) = \frac{d}{dt}1 = 0$$

Here $A\cdot B = A_{ij}B_{ij}$. The trick for $M=\mathbb{1}$ is

$$D(\det)|_1 = \mathbb{1},$$

so the above differentiation equation reads ${\rm tr}(\gamma^\prime(0))=0$. However in the general case

$$D(\det)|_M = {\rm Cof}(M)$$

the cofactor matrix. As far as I see ${\rm Cof}(M) \cdot X = 0$ is of no use. Any ideas out there?
Thanks.

Comment: I just realized $\mathrm{Cof}(M) = \det(M)M^{-\mathrm{T}}$, so $\mathrm{Cof}(M)\cdot X = \det(M)M^{-\mathrm{T}} \cdot X = \det(M)\mathrm{tr}(M^{-1}X) = 0 $ which is equivalent to $\mathrm{tr}(M^{-1}X) = 0$. This also answeres the follow-up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by a matrix $M$ is a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to itself. It is also continuous, differentiable,..., whatever. Furthermore, if $M\in SL_n$ multiplication by $M$ maps any element of the group to another element. So if $T$ is the well-known tangent space of $SL_n$ at the identity, then surely
$$MT=\{MX\mid X\in T\}$$
is the tangent space at $M$.

Observe that because $MTM^{-1}=T$ we have $MT=TM$. IOW you can multiply from the left or from the right as you see fit.

If $\gamma(t)$ is a path thru the identity, then $M\gamma(t)$ is a path thru $M$. Also $\dfrac d{dt}(M\gamma(t))=M\dfrac d{dt}\gamma(t)$ etc.

Comment: A group manifold, variety, whatever is always homogeneous, and we can move a local structure elsewhere by translations. Sometimes using conjugation action is necessary. When we know how to combine things at/near the identity, we need to first move objects located at $M$ to the identity, then do the combining and then move them back to $M$.

Comment: Yes, true. I did not post my question exactly. See the follow-up http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231926/tangent-space-of-symsln-mathbbr-at-arbitrary-point . Thank you for your answer.